# SQL Server trigger to fill in Null values based on filename and value above

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I need to create a trigger that will help me fill in the rest of my Project name column. The project name comes from my Hostname column, however I may have multiple sets of Hostnames on import. My current trigger allows me to fill in my Project column like so:

Current trigger results:

[image]

I need to update my trigger so it fills in the rest of the null values and populates the Project name with the corresponding hostname.

Desired trigger results:

[image]

I need this trigger to work dynamically, so it will fill in any amount of rows and project on import. I'd also like to use Filename as a criteria for the update so it won't accidentally update any other sets of data imported.

Current Trigger Code:
This is the current trigger I have that allows me to get the project name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trgUpdateProject]
ON [myTable]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE m
SET m.[Project] = m.[Host name]
FROM inserted i
JOIN [myTable] m ON i.[FileName] = m.[FileName]
WHERE UPPER(m.[Mfg]) IN (SELECT UPPER([Mfg_ID]) FROM [tblMfg_ID]) 
and m.[Project] IS NULL

END
```

Comment: can you show us your current trigger ?

Comment: sure thing. just added

Comment: Can you please show us data of `m.[Mfg]` and `SELECT UPPER([Mfg_ID]) 
                             FROM [tblMfg_ID]` ??

Comment: First of all, the "value above" note **requires** a proper ordering expression - a sequential ID, or a date/time or something else that your data can be **ordered by** so you can have "value above" (or previous / next value). Secondly: you're not using the `Inserted` pseudo table that exists inside a trigger and that holds the newly inserted rows - you're always updating **the whole table** which is going to be horribly slow after a while

Comment: Unfortunately, some of that data is sensitive which is why I didn't include any of it. Basically its a map of known manufacturers that correspond with the hostnames that are used for our project names.

Comment: @marc_s does the row_id not qualify as an ordering expression? I also have a column with just incremental row numbers and another for created date. Also i was unaware of the inserted pseudo table until recently. I will most likely change my triggers to use that. Lastly please be friendly, I'm still learning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Trigger to fill in value based off File Name on Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954503/sql-server-trigger-to-fill-in-value-based-off-file-name-on-import)

Answer (score 1):

assuming RowID is the primary key of the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trgUpdateProject]
ON [myTable]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE m
SET    m.[Project] = n.[Host name]
FROM   inserted i
       INNER JOIN [myTable]   m  ON i.RowID = m.RowID
       INNER JOIN [tblMfg_ID] n  ON m.Mfg   = n.Mfg_ID
WHERE  i.[Project] IS NULL

END
```

Comment: something like this may work. I will test it out tomorrow. thanks

Comment: by joining on mfg, it will produce the same row as the one where project is already filled in

Comment: the `WHERE` clause will exclude that

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trgUpdateProject]
ON [myTable]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE m
    SET m.[Project] = m.[Host name]
    FROM [myTable] m 
    --This grabs the MFG ID in a mapping table. If they match, that hostname is the projectname
    WHERE UPPER(m.[Mfg]) IN (SELECT UPPER([Mfg_ID]) 
                             FROM [tblMfg_ID]) 

END
```

Comment: If [Project] is null then query will be executed(updates) else  its not updates  so i removed "project is null " command.

Comment: The trigger code I posted was for the trigger currently in place to fill in the project names with corresponding hostnames. My question was to fill in the null values with their proper project names.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below query to get the desired results.

If the table is in the below form

```
create table updproject(
rowid varchar(20) not null unique,
filename varchar(20),
project varchar(20),
hostname varchar(20),
)
```

Use below trigger to update project based on host name

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trgUpdateProject]
ON updproject
FOR INSERT,update
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE  @st1 varchar(5)
SELECT @st1 = SUBSTRING(hostname,CHARINDEX('t',hostname)+1,1) from inserted
UPDATE updproject
SET updproject.Project = 'Host'+@st1
where rowid = (select rowid from inserted) and project is null
END
```

Please try inserting a row in the below form

```
 insert into updproject (rowid,filename,hostname) values ('abc123', 'abc1' ,'HostN-012')
```

output:

```
rowid filename project hostname
abc123 abc1    HostN   HostN-012
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort but the hostnames provided in the example are only a placeholder. the hostnames could be named anything and not always a set amount of characters.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Will there be a string like %Host% in the hostname column ?